Calibrating CIR to bond prices
Consider the Hull-White model -
$$dr_t = (\theta_t - kr_t)dt + \sigma_tdw_t$$
We can/have to calibrate $\theta_t$ to the current bond prices $P(0,t)$ and make it consistent with the HJM framework. For Hull-White model, there is an explicit formula for $\theta_t$ in terms of $\sigma_t$, bond prices, forward rates and its derivatives.
Can we get a similar formula for CIR model -
$$dr_t = (\theta_t - kr_t)dt + \sigma_t\sqrt{r_t}dw_t$$

CIR Model
\begin{equation}
dr_t = (\theta_t - k r_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt{r_t} \, dW_t
\end{equation}
Consistency with HJM Framework

Bond Price Dynamics: In the HJM framework, the bond price (P(t,T)) under a risk-neutral measure (Q) satisfies:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dP(t,T)}{P(t,T)} = r_t dt + \sigma_P(t,T) dW_t
\end{equation}

Forward Rate Dynamics: The instantaneous forward rate (f(t,T)) is defined by:
\begin{equation}
f(t,T) = -\frac{\partial \ln P(t,T)}{\partial T}
\end{equation}

HJM Drift Condition: The drift of the forward rate in the HJM framework under the risk-neutral measure is:
\begin{equation}
df(t,T) = \alpha(t,T) dt + \sigma_f(t,T) dW_t
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\alpha(t,T) = \frac{\partial f(t,T)}{\partial T} + \sigma_f(t,T) \int_t^T \sigma_f(t,u) du
\end{equation}


CIR Model Calibration
For the CIR model, we need to express $\theta_t$ in terms of observable quantities (like bond prices $P(0,t)$ or forward rates $f(0,t)$ and model parameters.

Bond Price in CIR Model: The price of a zero-coupon bond $(P(t,T)$ under the CIR model can be expressed as:
\begin{equation}
P(t,T) = A(t,T) e^{-B(t,T) r_t}
\end{equation}
where $A(t,T)$ and $B(t,T)$ are functions derived from solving the CIR bond pricing PDE.

Forward Rate $f(t,T)$: Given the bond price formula, the forward rate can be obtained as:
\begin{equation}
f(t,T) = -\frac{\partial \ln P(t,T)}{\partial T}
\end{equation}


Deriving $\theta_t$
Using the bond price expression, we can derive the forward rate dynamics in the CIR framework. The key steps are:

Drift of (r_t): The drift term in the CIR model is $(\theta_t - k r_t)$.

HJM Drift Condition: Ensure that the drift of the forward rate $f(t,T)$ matches the HJM drift condition.

Matching Drifts: By equating the drift of the forward rate in the CIR model to the HJM drift, we can solve for $\theta_t$.


Step-by-Step Derivation

Compute the Forward Rate Dynamics in CIR:
\begin{equation}
df(t,T) = \left(\frac{\partial f(t,T)}{\partial t} + \sigma \sqrt{r_t} \frac{\partial f(t,T)}{\partial r_t}\right) dt + \sigma \sqrt{r_t} \frac{\partial f(t,T)}{\partial r_t} dW_t
\end{equation}

Equate to HJM Drift:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f(t,T)}{\partial t} + \sigma \sqrt{r_t} \frac{\partial f(t,T)}{\partial r_t} = \frac{\partial f(t,T)}{\partial T} + \sigma_f(t,T) \int_t^T \sigma_f(t,u) du
\end{equation}

Solve for $\theta_t$:
By ensuring the drift terms match, we can isolate $\theta_t$ and express it in terms of observable quantities.



https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model
Section "Bond Pricing".
Has to be solved numerically; this is as far as you can get.
